# VBA - Name Excel Table Range and Paste Into Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

Can you name a Range("O1:AG15") with a specific cell text.

IE A1 contains "1234" ... name Range("O1:AG15") "1234" then copy that range into Worksheet2 (Not important where).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a `Named Range` (workbook scope) that refers to `Range("O1:AG15")` in "Sheet1" use the line below:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add _
            Name:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, _
            RefersTo:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:AG15")
```

To copy this `Range` to "Sheet2" use the code line below:

```
Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

---

**Edit 1**: for Debug

```
Dim RangeName As String

RangeName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
MsgBox RangeName

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:AG15")
```

Comment: Im getting a runtime error 1004 - The name that you entered is not valid?

Comment: where ? first line ? do you have any value in your  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` ? what is it ?

Comment: First line A1 contains 1234

Comment: @ShawnCartwright in "Sheet1" ? is it a value ? or formula ?

Comment: @ShawnCartwright I can't see any reason why it's not running for you, try my edited code under **Edit 1** for debugging this